# Database is not responding until all requests are submitted successfully: MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 for Web API and below is my JQuery Ajax request which saves records concurrently. Below is the code..

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var 
     data={'Role' : "Role"+i},
     request = $.ajax({
        url:                'http://localhost:1234/Practise/public/api/SaveRoleApi',
        type:               "POST",
        data:               JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType:        "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async:  true,
        success: function(d){ console.log(d); }
     });
}
```

I am using for loop to save 100 records. Please check there is `async:  true,`. Reason I said it is saving records concurrently because the requests are being submitted randomly although I confirmed that all requests are being submitted successfully.

My Question is: I can't submit select statement `select * from tblrole` until all the above ajax requests are submitted.

Problem is: Database is not responding until all requests has been submitted.

What should I do to retrieve records during the Post request(s) submission is in progress?

Below are my Phpmyadmin details.

[image]

Comment: sounds like the SaveRoleApi is performing a table lock.  Check your php code

Comment: Are you using innodb? Do you have some sort of table locking enabled? Are you maxing out your mysql connections and causing the rest to wait? You could try offloading this to a queue. There's a lot of missing information and lots of possibilities to try. Which of them have you tried?

Comment: @Forbs: I am using Laravel 5.3 framework. In Which part of my code should I check for table lock?

Comment: Sorry, no idea as I don't program in Laravel.

Comment: @Blake: Where should I check for table locking option? No, I am not doing anything like one request at a time and others to wait. You can check my requests are concurrent. I used `async:  true,` in ajax. Can you explain more in details about offloading ? Should I follow this article? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/

Comment: @Helper see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues -- Also, you can turn on mysql's logging in your my.cnf if you really need to get into the nitty gritties. I'd guess your tables are innodb, so google innodb table locking.

Comment: Does this means that using Queue, all the concurrent requests should be converted into sequential request? My above code is just a sample code to test if the code can support concurrent request or not.

Comment: InnoDB does not lock tables except for things like `ALTER TABLE`; MyISAM does for lots of things.

Comment: Are you using the same browser and the same webserver for your app and phpmyadmin ? Usually a server waits for one request to finish before it lets you do another. Try using a different browser for phpmyadmin.

Comment: Are you sending 100 records to be stored in a database table?

Comment: Yes, In a loop in Jquery ajax with async option.

Comment: Can you show us the database-related code in `SaveRoleApi`?

Comment: Important question (although it won't appears as important) - is the web server Apache?

Comment: Ok, then this is what happens - it's Apache's fault actually. It uses an optimization step called pipelining and it tries to negotiate with your browser in order to use a single TCP connection for everything (we have http2 nowadays for that). However, it's not a good piece of software so every request you try to make, be it from another tab or instance of your browser **will not produce results** until those ajaxes are done. Basically, your MySQL works, JS works fine, it's the web server that installs a brake between everything. Solution: ditch Apache. I never found out how to disable that.

Comment: Also, that was the reason why I went with `nginx` and never, ever looked back. Alternatively, don't use phpmyadmin and use an alternative which won't use your browser (SQLYog, MySQL Workbench, HeidiSQL etc.). Good luck!

Comment: This problem should not happen in a production server when you every request have a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is the confusion...

`async` has to do with getting a *response*, not on *submitting* in parallel.

The code you presented is single-threaded -- *submit* one request, *submit* another request, ..., but don't wait for them to *finish*.

Then, only after 100 *submits*, perform the `SELECT`.

I would guess that AJAX chokes on that many submissions and gets stalled.

Comment: what's the correct code to read data when multiple concurrent request are submitted?

Comment: If you could send _one_ AJAX_ request with all 100 items, things will be a lot faster.  A single "batch" `INSERT` of 100 rows will be 10 times as fast.

Comment: And don't forget the overhead of an extra 99 roundtrips, an extra 99 connections to MySQL to be opened, etc.

Comment: but the same is true when concurrent 100 connections send request to server

Comment: Can you provide the `INSERT` SQL statement.  How big is tblrole?

Comment: IN table there is one column of String type and one Auto Increment column

Answer (score 1):

Smells like you have `autocommit=0` and never issued a `COMMIT`.  Please show us the connect code, plus some of the SQL statements.  I assume it is in `SaveRoleApi`.

Smells like "table locking", which you get from MyISAM.  If your tables are that, change to InnoDB.

Comment: where can i check `autocommit=0` and please which thing i should show in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the same browser and the same webserver for your app and phpmyadmin ? Usually a server waits for one request to finish before it lets you do another. Try using a different browser for phpmyadmin.

Comment: This is due to the server waiting for the session file handle to close after each request. You can address this by closing the session handle in your code as soon as you no longer need to write information to thr $_SESSION variable using [`session_write_close`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php).

Comment: Thanks Tom. I never got around finding out what caused this. Thought it might be the root of Rick James Problem.